# Multiple files upload through wwv_flow_files in Oracle Apex 4.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have selected Storage type as Apex dynamic table: wwv_flow_files
But DML statement is not letting the BLOB file to save in dynamic table. Once it saves my further process plan is to move data from wwv_flow_files to own table with the help of process or dynamic action.
Your help is valuable.

Regards,
Anshul Ayushya

Comment: The title of your question is related to "multiple files". What does that mean, do you want to upload multiple files at once? If so, that was added in APEX 5.1 (the title says 4.1 while the tags mention 5 and 5.1). What version of APEX are you using?

Comment: You said: But DML statement is not letting the BLOB file to save in dynamic table. What does that mean? Do you get an error? If so, which one?

Answer (score 0):

Addition of a process for each file browser item will work with below plsql code:

```
insert into CASE_DOCUMENT
```

( CASE_ID,
     DOCUMENT_NAME,
REPORT_TYPE,
DOCUMENT_DATE,
DOCUMENT_CATEGORY,
DESCRIPTION,
DOCUMENT
   , file_type
   , filename
   )
select :P59_case_ID,
     :P59_DOCNAME,
:P59_REPORT_TYPE,
:P59_DOCUMENT_DATE,
:P59_DOCUMENT_CATEGORY,
:P59_DOCDESCRIPTION,
blob_content
   , mime_type
   , filename
from wwv_flow_files WHERE NAME = :P59_DOCUMENT;

DELETE FROM wwv_flow_files WHERE NAME= :P59_DOCUMENT;